# How to copy the search result (using Swiper) from search buffer in doom emacs?

Tags: doom, swiper

I search the line containing rowid in the buffer, and want to copy all the lines in the result window. How to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the swiper search, type `C-c C-o`

That will open a separate buffer with the search results.  From there you can copy whatever you like just like you can from any other buffer.

Comment: That's very useful, one issue is that in the buffer, it has a begin as the filename in each line. e.g filename:line: myline.  But I don't need the repeated filename

Comment: I suggest opening a new Emacs Stack Exchange question asking about that.